# How to best handle having thousands of DOM elements in browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I'm working on building a sort of "word cloud" in the browser using html and javascript. The idea is to have a while bunch of words on the screen each one maybe with a different size or different color.

Issue is that I may need 100k+ words on the screen as it is a big area that will be covered. I have attempted to do this using pure html, using span elements with different styles for each word. However this approach makes the browser choke as I assume it is rendering too many DOM elements. Approaches using tables and divs were also unsuccessful.

I am wondering if I am approaching this the wrong way? I suspect there is a more performant way to do this, perhaps using canvas or svg, though these will require more work to integrate I would assume. I also want the user to be able to interact with some of the words such as deleting them or changing them. This makes the html approach seem easiest.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: @Solo the problem is (atleast I think) that all the words are all in page view so there is no scrolling

Comment: Best way to handle this is not to render all elements if it becomes a performance problem. There's a point where it's more efficient to track scroll position with JS and calculate based on that which items to render. This tehnique is usually used with long lists and it's called virtual list.

Comment: https://www.bewonersaanzet.nl/wijkensites.dordrecht/gx/ZmlmarnJC.jpeg This is what you are trying to achieve right? But with like 1000 words.

Comment: If there's no scrolling,you need to find a way to break it up to different screens or chunks, e.g show only some amount and show more if you zoom in but it's getting too complicated. Might be easier to test **SVG** or **canvas** and see if that helps.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at svg for sure, I recall reading about d3 before which leveraged this, maybe that's an option. The scrolling option is also good I think, though zooming in and out might end up accidentally overloading the thing if the user does it in the browser.